# Node.js + node-xmpp.js + mongoseIM

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, xmpp, ejabberd

Tengo un dilema estructural para mi aplicación. 
Actualmente tengo una aplicación consumiendo un API Rest hecho con Node y MongoDB. Y quiero agregarle la funcionalidad de chat. Estuve leyendo y creo que la mejor opción es usa el protocolo XMPP para ello encontré mongooseIM que está orientado a aplicaciones mobile. El tema es que no soporta mongoDB (mi BD actual). Entonces pensé en utilizar node-xmpp para comunicarme con mongooseIM y registrar al usuario desde Node y mandarle al cliente la auth para mongooseIM y conectar el servicio de chat del cliente a este server.
Mas o menos así seria la arquitectura.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy un poco quemado ya de tanto leer alternativas y documentación, por eso me gustará consultarles si esta bien planteado o estoy mal encaminado.
De ser así que opciones son mejores según su experiencia.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: la que mencionas puede ser una posibilidad otra opción también si tienes muchos problemas es desarrollar tu mismo la comunicación usando a node como servidor, eso se lograría utilizando webSockets para implementar el chat y asi lograr la comunicación